# 110vac to 24vac transformer question

Tags: power, led

I am trying to use this:

[image]

To work with these:

[image]

When I hook up transformer, I hook up hot(black)from source to one red wire and neutral(white) to other red wire on primary. Which makes 24vac on secondary side.

Image of lights, says 24vac on one line and GND on other, I assume GND is ground? The only way I could get the 24vac on one of the black secondary wires was to hook up the other secondary wire to the ground(green wire) from source. Is this the correct and safe method or is there another?

Comment: Do you have a link to the light itself? I looked at ipixellight website, and all their chainable lights are DC. All the power supplies on their site are also DC. I suspect the second picture is wrong, and you need DC supply.

Answer (score 1):

### GND vs ground

GND in DC-electrical is slang for **Common** or **Return** voltage -- the reference point they call 0 volts.  **It has absolutely nothing to do with the safety earthing on AC mains power**, which always uses a green, yellow-green or bare wire.  In AC, current must never ordinarily flow on Safety Ground; it only flows *during* fault conditions.

This is just a weird design convention, akin to the way "DC negative" is actually the electron *source* (what's up with that?)

So, if you have any background in AC mains, you must have your DC hat, and your AC hat.

- When your AC hat is on, then black is hot and white is neutral, and green/bare is safety ground.  Or you're in Europe and it's brown/blue for hot/neutral.
- When your DC hat is on, then red is positive hot and black is common/return, and that's called GND even though it's not actually.

### Connecting things on the AC mains side to things on the DC side

Never do that.  If there's any connecting to be done, that is the job of the power supply.  So don't do anything mutton-headed like:

- Connecting DC "GND" (black) to AC equipment safety ground (green/bare).
- Connecting DC "Common" (black) to AC "common" (white/blue neutral).

Any of those scenarios will create a hazard situation if a trivial wire failure in the AC mains were to also occur.  For instance a broken/disconnected AC safety ground + a ground fault in an unrelated AC appliance could **energize the chassis of your DC device at 120/230V**.  We don't want that, and the UL listing for that power supply requires it have internal insulation as an additional safeguard against that happening. Any jumpering between the LV side and the mains side defeats that insulation, voids the UL listing, and thus violates the mains electrical codes.

### GFCI/RCD vs DC systems

You notice that DC systems carry ordinary service current on the thing they call GND.  **AC systems do not**.  All current is carried on hot(s) and neutral, and only fault current is carried on safety ground.   As a result, GFCI/RCD systems monitor only the hot and neutral wires for equal current, and ignore safety ground altogether.

*We're on the AC mains side here*. 
[image]

So anything you could possibly do that would cause current to hop from the brown or gray wire, to the green wire, would be extremely bad -- it would disrupt the fundamental systems design of mains power, and also throw a monkey-wrench in the functioning of the GFCI.

### Transformer quality

I recognize the marks plainly: this is a cheap transformer bought mail order, and it's from the Alibaba junkstream.  The CS is a lie; the RoHS is smoke and mirrors.  It doesn't have a UL listing or comparable. It's not legal to install onto the AC mains. (NEC 110.2).

However, listed 24 volt AC transformers of good quality are readily available from any heating and air conditioning supplier. They are universally used for HVAC control and doorbells.  They either mount in a junction box knockout, or replace the lid of the junction box, with the AC mains terminals on the inside and the low voltage terminals on the outside.  Most are only 40 VA, but see what your lights take.

Comment: Thank you for all that information.  GND is return, now it makes much better sense.  Depending on where these go and the layout, will depend how big and how many transformers, the supplier offered these "free".  Last time I used dc lights, figured try ac this time.  Would you hook the ac green(ground) from source to chassi ?

Comment: I should have mentioned the UL listed 40 VA transformers are like $13.  I would hook up the transformers exactly as the instructions and labeling say.  This is a critical area of work because of the risk of electrical drownings. They often find 3 bodies in the pool, the victim and 2 rescuers. This tends to draw very strong enforcement actions, and every aspect of your work will be scrutinized. GFCI helps tremendously, I'd even call it a "get out of jail free" card.

Comment: I understand, it's all about safety and being compliant.  I'll look into some UL transformers, each light takes 3.3watts, first sign is 100ish lights.

Answer (score 0):

yes that's correct connect one black wire to red on the light, 
connect the gray to the other black wire.

a connection to ground is not necessary for the lights to operate.

and if they are being used underwater probably not a good idea either.

Comment: Would it also be correct to ground the case to the ground wire also, if using a gfi?

Comment: Jasen, most (if not all) electrical codes do not require grounding of the low voltage wiring if it is less than 50V. In some cases, _especially when used to illuminate pools_, it is specifically **prohibited**. I believe the grey wire is called "GND" on the second image only by convention, it is not even grounded on the picture. In fact, the three rightmost terminals (GND, N, L) are not connected on the picture. So, connecting secondary to GND is not necessary, and probably not desired

Comment: you could well be right

Answer (score -1):

I do not think from what I see that you have enough current. And I'd I were doing this I would not series these lights I'd parallel them. Seriesing thembis not good engineering practice because each effects the operation of the other, where in parallel they function independently.

Comment: Parallel as in plugging into each other vs hooking one black wire from secondary side of transformer to red wire on first light in series and other black wire from transformer on the last light of the series on the gnd wire?    Here is 2 sets of 16, using a "y" connector from transformer, I put a #12 in the #15 spot, [Video] (https://youtu.be/8WyKVOQPIT4)